# Correct way to add 3 to sum(1/k!) to get 8

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

The recent spat of 22+4 puzzles took me back to 1974, when my high school math teacher (and cross-country coach), Dr James Quinlan, asked us to solve $$3+\sum_{k=0}^\infty
 \dfrac{1}{k!} = 8$$.

Comment: I don't see any variables.  What are we solving for?

Comment: Or are we supposed to prove it?

Comment: Why is n in the title but not in the post?  I'm done now :)

Comment: You can't really prove it unless you prove that $3 + e = 8$. Because the sum evaluates to $e$.

Comment: What if you take e as 5?

Comment: e *is* the fifth letter of the alphabet

Comment: which alphabet?

Comment: @JaredGoguen You should post that as an answer

Comment: agreed ... depending on which alphabet he uses

Comment: Is it in the Greek alphabet, $3 + \epsilon = \theta$?

Comment: Or, in 7-segment displays, the overlap of 3 and E make 8?

Comment: @NateDiamond I like the 7-segment approach.  Not the one I had in mind, but avoids the B/8 issue. Nice!

Answer (score 17):

<sub>This was just posted by Joe Z., quickly downvoted, and then deleted. I don't understand why. It seemed like a legitimate and puzzle-y answer to me. I am posting a more complete version now so people can tell me if I'm wrong.</sub>

---

The equation evaluates to be

> $3+e=8$     because     $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k!} = e$     by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

If you capitalize that and squish them together, it looks like this:

> [image: MATH]
>  $3 + E = E + 3 \to E\hspace{0.2em}3 \to E\hspace{-0.1em}3 \to E\hspace{-0.3em}3 \to 8$

Comment: I would up-vote 5 times if I could.  A somewhat more elegant, imo, solution exists.  I'll give it a few days to see if it gets posted.

Comment: @EngineerToast I posted it as a sort of joke answer that still kinda worked, and when I saw that people immediately didn't like it (2 downvotes in 1 minute is a pretty strong message), I deleted it.

Comment: @JoeZ. Don't know why it played out that way, but I did see it as it was happening.

Comment: @JoeZ. I do feel badly about that. I'll put your name is so all glory to Joe Z.

Comment: The last transformation is a bit of a stretch imo.

Comment: @JeremyArgent I can try banging my head against the wall a few times, maybe that will make that "B" like looking symbol look like an "8". I liked Jared's solution treating e as the fifth letter of the alphabet. I didn't get your "which alphabet" comment, is it some kind of hint? Most alphabets that have the letter e in them would do.

Comment: regarding hints, the story about Dr Quinlan is factual and does not contain hints, though I could have chosen a fake name and turned it into a hint.

Comment: @EngineerToast The "glory" thing makes it sound creepy, lol.

Comment: Also you could write this solution as E = 8 - 3 which is just taking the 3 from the 8 to get E

Answer (score 2):

Did he write it on the blackboard perchance? If so

> define $l=\frac5e$
>  now
>  $$3+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{l}{k!}=8$$

---

Another possibility is

> To read the concatenation in Russian:
>  $$3+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=3+e=\text{зе}=\text{ж}=8$$
>  Since зе is pronounced the same as ж, the 8th letter in the alphabet. 
>
>
>  Although this would probably be better asked as:
>  $$3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=8$$

Comment: Umm... No, it is not pronounced the same, it's more like "ze" vs. "zh"

Comment: @Akiiino thanks for letting me know! At the time I listened to pronunciation on the web and they sounded the same, but I am not Russian and have never studied it.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, the equation simplifies to:

> $3+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k!}=3+e$

Using the trivial letter number substitution cipher leads to:

> $3+5=8$ since $e$ is the fifth letter of the English alphabet.